# Baggage transfer from Air India to Qantas on same booking

Tags: luggage, check-in, dxb, air-india, qantas

I am travelling to London with a transit in Dubai. My Air India flight arrives in Dubai (Terminal 1) at 22:25. The onward flight to London is with Qantas at 02:10 from Terminal 3.

Will my luggage be transferred to the Qantas flight or do I have to check it in again? What procedure do I need to follow on arrival in Dubai?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Air India about this issue?

Comment: Are you flying on the same through ticket, or have two separate tickets?

Comment: i havent contacted Air India yet :( . Im flying on the same ticket...

Answer (score 3):

If you are on the same ticket, your luggage is normally checked through.

There are rare exceptions, but then the airline would explicitly tell you at check-in, and probably before deboarding again.